# Max and min elements in partially ordered set

Tags: order-theory

Consider the relations of order $\circ_1, \circ_2$ and $\leq = \circ_1 \cap \circ_2$ on set $M = \{a,b,c,d\}$ given by:
$$a \circ_1 b \circ_1 d \qquad \qquad (1)$$
$$a \circ_1 b \circ_1 c \qquad \qquad (2)$$
$$b \circ_2 d \circ_2 c \circ_2 a \qquad (3)$$
The task is to find all minimal and maximal elements in poset $(M, \leq)$.
My approach is to simply select intersections from given inequalities:

From $(1)$ and $(3)$ we get:

$$b\circ_1 d, \qquad b\circ_2 d \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad b \leq d$$
From $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get:
$$b \circ_1 c, \qquad b\circ_2 d \circ_2 c \Rightarrow b \circ_2 c \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad b \leq c$$

So minimal element is $\{b\}$ and maximal elements are $\{c,d\}$.

How true are these arguments and should we add element $\{a\}$ to minimal or/and maximal elements set, since it is not comparable to others?

Comment: Are you sure it's minimum/maximum, or might it be minimal/maximal? Because minimum and maximum are unique, when they exist.

Comment: @amrsa My bad, edited

Comment: then just add $a$ as a maximal and minimal element: it's both.

Comment: The element $a$ is maximal because there is no other above it; and it's minimal because there is no other below it. Isolated elements in posets (that is, the ones which are neither greater nor smaller than others) are always minimal and maximal.

Comment: K, thank you for clarification!